# go run throes error " undefined reference to `dlopen'"

Tags: go, shared-libraries

I am trying to integrate Golang script with existing C shared library.
The C shared library in turn loads other shared libraries at run time.

While I am trying to run
go run gotest.go

it throws error

```
./libtest.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
./libtest.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
./libtest.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
./libtest.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have created separate C executable to load this libtest.so at run time and that is working properly.

Any idea what should be done to fix the issue?

I have tried following commands

> sudo go build -compiler=gccgo -gccgoflags="-ltest" gotest.go
>
> also tried the command
>
> sudo go build -compiler=gccgo -gccgoflags="-ltest -ldl" gotest.go
>
> Also tried the command
>
> go run gotest.go
>
> ===============================================

Here is the code I am using

```
testapi.h
typedef Students{
        char name[40];
        int  id;
} Student;

Student* getStudent();

test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"
#include "testapi.h"

int rc = 0;
Student *s = 0;
Student* getStudent(){
   
   rc = loadmylib(); //This function loads another shared library
   if (!rc)
   {
       rc = initlib(); //This calls dlsym to get the necessary function from opened shared library
       if (!rc)
       {
           s= (student *)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    
           //use the function pointer received from dlsym to populate the Student struct 's'
       }
    }
    return s;
}
```

I have following entries in my gotest.go file

```
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I.
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -ltest -ldl
#include "testapi.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

type Student struct{
     name string
     id int
}

func main() {
    st := C.getStudent()
    fmt.Println("Name: ", string(st.name))
}
```

I have copied testapi.h, gotest.go, mylib.h, libmylib.so, libtest.so in the same directory.
Then run the command

> go run gotest.go

It has thrown the error " error: undefined reference to 'getStudent' "

What am I doing wrong here?
Am I supposed to run command

> sudo go build -compiler=gccgo -gccgoflags="-ltest" gotest.go

Comment: What do you mean by "Golang script"? Are you compiling a Go program that uses `cgo` to use the C shared library?

Comment: @OP Exactly what command did you try? Please quote it.

Comment: Added the commands I have tried in the post

Comment: You could try to change line 5 in gotest.go: `#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -ltest -ldl`

Comment: Why are you using `gccgo`? (and you should never use, or need to use sudo to compile). as ZsigmondLőrinczy suggested, add `-ldl` to your `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working after adding -ldl in the gotest.go as suggested by Zsigmond Lorinczy

Comment: Now the dlopen error is resolved but the C function exposed by libtest.so is not visible by gotest.go while running the command go run gotest.go. It sayas " error: undefined reference to 'getStudents' "

Am I supposed to run any other command?

Comment: @user3218590: I don't understand. You said it's working now, which means you built the binary, so why are you calling `go run` instead of executing that binary you just built? (and stop using gccgo for now. It's only adding to the confusing)

Comment: @JimB Last time I just used the command go run gotest.go and it resolved the dlopen error. But now it says undefined reference to getStudent. What command should I use to build?

Comment: You can use `go build` or `go install` (`go run` uses `go build` in a temp dir), but if you build the binary, you at least look at the shared object dependencies. You're either not finding the library, or it's linking the incorrect one. Relative paths don't work in cgo directives, try `-L${SRCDIR}`, though that ties the executable to the path of the package source when dynamically linking.